# Android Gmail not sending attachment when started by Intent

Tags: android, email, gmail

My app launches an `Intent` to send an email and passes a `Uri` for a PDF file through the intent to the new email activity. I want to make it very clear where the problem lies because I've spent a lot of time testing.

Everything works fine, the new email is shown with the attachment with the correct name and size. I'm having an issue when the user uses Gmail to send the email, it occurs only when **BOTH** of the following happen:

- **When the user selects the Gmail app**
- **AND when the user selects an account in the *from* line where that account is syncing gmail**

**The Issue:**
The attachment is not received on the other end. It's shown properly when composing the email, correct name and size, but it's not received on the other end. No error messages, nothing about "file not found" in the logcat.

**When the user unchecks "Sync Gmail" in device settings, the issue goes away**. Accounts where gmail is NOT synced, it works fine and every attachment is received. And **every other email app works fine regardless of sync enabled**. This causes issues for users that want to sync gmail, and use gmail to send attachments. The attachment seems to come through once, but when sending another attachment to the same address, new attachments don't come through.

[Here is the logcat filtered by Gmail](https://pastebin.com/BnMbhG3K)

Again, not seeing any error messages. The "sync enabled" option seems to prevent gmail from sending attachments properly. Again this is only with the gmail app. Inbox works fine with sync enabled.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just started experiencing this issue, though disabling sync doesn't seem to have any effect for me. Did you come across a fix?

Comment: @AdamPaxton I did not find a fix unfortunately. Still can't explain this behavior. I just instructed users of my app to not use gmail.